# Docker Samba Container performance issue

Tags: docker, samba

This is my question that maybe some of you will find it stupid, but it wouldn't hurt me because i know that i am a newbie on the Docker system.

I have successfully set up a running container :

- a samba V3 apps (cf https://github.com/dastrasmue/rpi-samba but there is a lot of others)
- its share successfully a mounted usb drive on my PI over my network

But i have a performance issue, i cannot do 2 operations at the same time, for example :

- copy a movie from this share to my computer
- explore this share from another computer

In fact, the second task is freezed until the first one has finished ?
It act just like if my samba can handle only one task at a time (single threaded)??

Maybe it is normal because of the use of docker (one container for one task).
Can anyone confirm this ? Or did someone succeed to handle multiple operation in the same time on a Samba container (or another).
Or just tell me it is not a good idea to use docker with samba :)

Ty